# Is there any control like folderBrowserDialog but for website links?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, hyperlink

In this case I select a directory and in my label4 I see the directory name I selected:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.folderBrowserDialog1.Description = "Select the directory that you are want to use as default and please verify if the chosen directory is accessible";
            if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string message = "Are you sure you want to select this directory ?";
                string caption = "Operation cancelled";
                MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
                DialogResult result;
                result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons);

                if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    mainUrl = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
                    label4.Text = mainUrl;
                }
            }
        }
```

But I want something in the same idea but to enter a website link address. For example when a user clicks the button, it will open some textBox or something. The user will then type in a website address or will paste in a link and clicking on it will ask for confirmation and then shot it in label4.

Comment: so what's wrong with textbox? platform?

Comment: Nawfal not wrong but how do i do it to act like this folder dialog ? Or how should i do it ? Now the link the user see it in a label4 inside a groupbox i put it in a groupbox so if the link is a very long the user will put the mouse on it and see a baloon with the complete link length. And near the groupbox close ot it i added a small button "Change WebSite" So what should i do when the user click on the button ?

Comment: You can roll your own form with a textbox on it (no big deal) and then open the form using `ShowDialog`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you're asking, then the solution is very simple. Im assuming you're wanting to display a webpage on your program when the user types in a URL into a text box. Im not quite sure what it has to do with fileBrowser, considering there are millions upon millions of websites, a "website browser" in the sense of a filer browser wouldn't work so well.

Anyhow, i believe what your asking can be implemented by assigning the Url attribute of a webBrowser control to the text of the label or text box or whatever you have the URL in.

```
webBrowser1.Url = label4.text
```

If this isnt what you're asking for, then im at a loss.